# How can I manually assign a static IP in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ipv6, netplan

I have a VPS server running Ubuntu 18.04 which has a /64 subnet of IPv6 addresses. For the purpose of this post, let's call it 2601:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa::/64. The VPS website says I can use any address within this subnet, however the server has an automatically assigned address of 2601:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx. I have configured my netplan to use a static IPv6, which is 2601:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa::1, however it looks like that did not completely work, as when I type ifconfig, I see two public IPv6 addresses: the IP address I configured, and the automatically assigned one as well. And I notice that the server is still using the automatically assigned IP. If I run "/sbin/ip -6 addr del 2601:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 dev ens3" and then run ifconfig, the automatically assigned IP is gone and the server uses the one I assigned, but the automatically assigned one reappears on its own after a few minutes or after rebooting. How can I permanently get the server to use the IPv6 that I assigned? Here's what I have tried: Editing netplan, changing config to disable ipv6 privacy addresses, disabling router advertisements (this did not work as I needed an ipv6 gateway, which my VPS provider would not provide to me)

Here is my netplan:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/23,'2601:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa::1/64']
      gateway4: xxx.xxx.xxx.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [My provider's IP]
      routes:
      - to: 169.254.0.0/16
        via: [My provider's IP]
        metric: 100
```

Comment: Try removing your manual IP and pinging it. Usually when an automatic assigned IP appears after assigning a manual, it's due to a detected conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to stop accepting [Router Announcement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Stateless_address_autoconfiguration_(SLAAC)). I know nothing about Ubuntu and the configuration file you are using, but if you are using systemd-networkd, you can stop it with `IPv6AcceptRA=no` under the `[Network]` section of the `.network` file that manages your NIC. If you are NOT (not even behind the scene; as I see `renderer: networkd`), running one of the following should do:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra=0
```

or even just

```
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.ens3.accept_ra=0
```

(Put either of them, without `sysctl -w`, to `/etc/sysctl.conf` or `/etc/sysctl.d/some_name.conf`, should make the setting persistent among boots)

You may want to check the current value of `net.ipv6.conf.ens3.accept_ra` (with `sysctl` but without `-w` and `=0`) first to see if it's the kernel (instead of systemd-networkd) that has been handling Router Announcement. If it's already `0`, then likely it's systemd-neworkd that has been doing the job.

**EDIT**: looks like you can add [`accept-ra: no`](https://netplan.io/reference#common-properties-for-all-device-types) to stop it

**EDIT 2**: The documentation states that `If unset use the host kernel default setting.`, so maybe `sysctl` is what you need after all. But AFAIK, systemd-networkd *always* takes over the job as long as it is configured to manage an interface, at least with a recent version of it. But I guess `accept-ra: no` would do anyway, supposing that stops both the kernel and systemd-networkd from accepting RA.

See also: [RFC 4862](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4862), [systemd.network(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html), [ip-sysctl.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt)

Comment: Thank you for the help, it worked after disabling router announcement

Comment: No problem. If it solved your problem, you can mark it as the solution.